# Changing upload_max_filesize in php.ini of XAMPP doesn't have an effect

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, xampp

I've set the value of `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` to 128M in the php.ini file of XAMPP. Also, when I display `phpinfo()` it says that the maximum file upload size is at 128 Megabytes.

However, when I try to upload a 512 Kilobytes big file via a default file upload form, there just appears the text "Couldn't upload the file!". Strangely enough, it works with smaller files like 158 Kilobytes.

Of course, I tried out to change the `max_file_uploads` value. I restarted the XAMPP server multiple times.

HTML Code:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- Avatar -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="avatar">Avatar</label>
        <input type="file" name="avatar">                           
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP Handling code:

```
// Avatar
        if (isset($_FILES['avatar'])) {
            $fileName = $_FILES['avatar']['name'];
            $tmpName = $_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'];
            $fileSize = $_FILES['avatar']['size'];
            $fileType = $_FILES['avatar']['type'];

            echo $fileName . " " . $fileSize . " " . $fileType . " - ";

            $newData['profile_picture'] = $this->fileModel->uploadFile($fileName, $tmpName, $fileSize, $fileType);
            unset($_FILES['avatar']);
        }
```

fileModel->uploadFile:

```
public function uploadFile($original_name, $tmpname, $size, $type)
{
    $target_dir = "files" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $filetype = pathinfo(basename($original_name), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $target_file = $target_dir . $this->generateName() . '.' . $filetype;
    $name = explode('.' . $filetype, explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $target_file)[1])[0];

    if (!move_uploaded_file($tmpname, $target_file)) {
        die('File couldn\'t be uploaded!');
    }

    $this->db->query('INSERT INTO files (name, original_name, type, size, path) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [$name, $original_name, $type, $size, $target_file]);

    return "/file/open/" . $name;
}
```

What's returned when uploading an image:

```
KingOfDog Logo.png 162649 image/png - Couldn't upload the file!
```

Here's what is returned when doing `var_dump($_FILES)`:

array(2) { ["avatar"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(18) "KingOfDog Logo.png" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(25) "D:\xamppi\tmp\phpED5E.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(162649) } ["header"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(4) ["size"]=> int(0) } }

I'm running CodeIgniter on PHP version 5.6.28 with XAMPP v3.2.2 on a local Windows machine. Also, I'm using Bootstrap and jQuery.

Comment: "Couldn't upload the file!" Did you set this error? post the code that handles the upload

Comment: @MehdiBounya No, I didn't set this error. In my whole project, PHPStorm couldn't find this string.

Comment: Please re edit your question with your upload code.

Comment: `print_r($_FILES);` will show you the  *real* error

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Finished.

Comment: @rtfm I don't see an error here: `array(2) { ["avatar"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(18) "KingOfDog Logo.png" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(25) "D:\xamppi\tmp\phpC0D0.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(162649) } ["header"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(4) ["size"]=> int(0) } }`

Comment: your right, so its an ussue with CodeIgniter

Comment: i dont see an `uploadFile` in the CodeIgniter docs

Comment: @rtfm It's a class I made myself. The post is now updated.

Comment: a. why not actually use codeigniter? b. the error message you say you get is not coming from your code.

Comment: @rtfm what do you mean with "why not actually use codeigniter?" I **am** using Codeigniter...

Comment: Have you thought about using codeigniter file upload library https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#the-controller You can use also codeigniter form helper https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html with https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_open_multipart

Comment: @wolfgang1983 The old code still doesn't work but thanks for your proposal to use the library. Currently it works just fine...

Comment: Let me tell ya something, I've had an issue similar to this. Turn off Apache, then turn it on again. That may help, because the PHP only loads ONCE so any changes you make to PHP you have to restart Apache. Just try it.

Comment: It seems to be path issue. The error message is nothing specific. What is the function - generateName? Is the path relative or absolute? Do you remember to add slashes? Does the directory you are trying to upload - exist?

Answer (score 0):

You also must increase `max_post_size` value as it is supper and file upload goes via POST request.